# Folding ABUS Lock will not UNLOCK

Tags: lock

My bike is locked to an indoor bike rack with a folding ABUS keyed bike lock.
Today I couldn't turn the key to release the lock after work.
No problem locking it in the morning.  Tried wiggling, banging, twisting and pulling on "link".  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hit it with a bigger hammer.

Comment: Also http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/new-d-lock-failed-locked-up and the search box top right with "lock stuck" has other helpful answers.

Comment: @Stevenroy While the suggested duplicate has some different details, the answer is the same for you.

Comment: Another thread to look at: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/34612/7309 - same make but different lock. The key point in getting it free was to smack it in the right place and direction *while jiggling the key*. Just noticed you've already got a link to my question, but the hit+jiggle means I haven't deleted my comment.

Comment: Could you find the lock online (if it's still on sale) and link to it? It might help us look for specifics

Comment: Thanks! I am heading back on the subway with my hammer and lube!

Comment: SUCCESS!  Sea Foam Deep Creep squirted into key hole and into "bolt end" of lock.  Some swift whacks with "Maxwell's Silver Hammer" and vigorous wiggling of lubed key and ta-da!  Road home a happy biker.

Comment: The lock is an ABUS BORDO Folding lock.http://www.abus.com/us/Recreational-Security/Bike-Safety-and-Security/Locks/Folding-locks/Bordo-6000

Answer (score 1):

Lock have typically two kinds of problems. How far can you push the key in? Does it go in only partly, or does it go in fully but then you can't turn it? Often the disks inside have rotated so that you can't get the key in completely. Then it helps if you take a stiff wire or thin screwdriver and wiggle it up and down in the keyhole, and then try again with the key. But if the key goes in but doesn't turn, then it might be clogged up with dirt, in this case degreaser might help. Make sure you dry the lock carefully afterwards and don't use oil or grease to lubricate, they will just attract dirt and clog it up again. If you want to lubricate, use dry lubricant like graphite.

Comment: What happens when you mix graphite with degreaser residue?

Comment: Surprisingly I've seen manufacturers' advice on bike locks to use light oil, even wd40 (which has only short-term lubricating properties) it's as if they're more worried about rust than dirt.

Comment: Thanks!  The key seems to go in all the way.  I am heading back on the Metro with a hammer and lube and back up key!

Answer (score 0):

You could try spraying some [WD-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40) in there. And then reach for a hammer.

Also check if your key isn't damaged.

Comment: Please explain how a degreaser would help, what the hammer is for and so on. We much prefer complete answers over short hints.

Comment: @Mσᶎ WD-40 also has some lubricating properties, no? There are probably better options though.

Comment: WD-40 is horrible for locks as the light oil attracts dirt and grit. Use a graphite or PTFE-based lubricant specifically designed for locks.